# Dual monitor problem

Tags: nvidia, multiple-monitors, google-chrome, monitor, ubuntu-mate

I am using a dual monitor setup and sometimes when I move chrome or vivaldi to the second monitor and maximize it, it gets stuck. It doesn't happen with any other windows only with these two browsers. Any workaround to stop this? I can only move them again if I restart them.

- Ubuntu 16.04
- MATE DE
- NVIDIA Card

Comment: try disabling hardware acceleration

Comment: that didn't solve the problem :(

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer! Right click the default chrome title bar and tick the "Use system title bar and borders". It looks much better too!